# Datetime.now.getTime() not returning correct value

Tags: apex, datetime

I am getting a timestamp for current datetime using the following code

```
public Static String getGenerateTimeStamp()
{
    system.debug('Datetime : '+ DateTime.now());
    system.debug('timestamp : '+ DateTime.now().getTime());
    return String.valueof(DateTime.now().getTime());
}
```

> 21:21:46.752 (752692000)|USER_DEBUG|[51]|DEBUG|Datetime : 2014-03-20 10:21:47
>
> 21:21:46.752 (752884000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[52]|System.debug(ANY)
>
> 21:21:46.752 (752891000)|USER_DEBUG|[52]|DEBUG|timestamp :
>   1395310907476

I am passing this timestamps as an part of an API request and it gave out a error message

> The  timestamp  is  expressed  in  the  number  of  seconds  since  January  1%2C  1970  00%3A00%3A00  GMT.   The  timestamp  value  MUST 
>   be  a  positive  integer.

On checking with some online convertors the datetime is of a date in 1985. I am not sure if its the getTime() method which is at fault . The timestamp value of `1395310907` seems to give the correct date. I am not sure from where the `476` is getting appended.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The timestamp that salesforce returns are the number of millisecons from January 1 1970, not the number of seconds.

Comment: Time for coffee i guess :P

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for [getTime()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_getTime) states:

> **getTime()**
>
> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
> represented by this DateTime object.

You're passing milliseconds into something that is expecting seconds. You could divide 1000 to convert it to seconds.

Answer (score 2):

`getTIme()` method returns the time in milliseconds.Therefore last 3 digits corresponds to millisecond time.
You can get the millisecond by using  `DateTime.now().millisecond()` and then subtract it from `DateTime.now().getTime()`

Comment: Or just divide by 1000